# Integral involving an impulse function (no Laplace)

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

[Integrals Problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdo6a.jpg)

Please, help me solve these problems without using Laplace. So on  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html
I found [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6ZP6.jpg) fundamenetal properties that I thought I could use to solve the problems, but I'm not sure if I applied them correctly. Here is my [work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xod5.jpg) so far for part a, but I don't know how to approach part b because the bounds are different. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [mathjax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: @postmortes Except the link to MathWorld,*all* OP's links points towards pictures uploaded via SE's internal image uploader,which assigns [*permenant* image URLs](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/291666/259305).  I've edited [over 50 tag wikis](//math.stackexchange.com/users/290189/gnusupporter-8964%E6%B0%91%E4%B8%BB%E5%A5%B3%E7%A5%9E-%E5%9C%B0%E4%B8%8B%E6%95%99%E6%9C%83?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), and *many* of them make reference to Wolfram MathWorld. These are *reliable* URLs. The *true* problem is the use of pictures as shortcut to typing [math](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22025/290189).

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 fair enough for the permanent URLs.  I agree with you about the real issue too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be going in the right direction. To my understanding, the limits of integration do not have to be the same. The only requirement is that the limits enclose the "position" of the impulse. For example:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\delta(t-2)dt = f(2) $$
This encloses the "position" of the impulse
$$\int_1^3 f(t)\delta(t-2)dt = f(2) $$
This does not
$$\int_3^4 f(t)\delta(t-2)dt = 0 $$